# Magento admin menu link not showing up

Tags: magento

I have created 2 modules (A and B) in Magento. Each of these modules are managed from the admin section.

I tried creating a menu link under cms(menu) in the admin section for each module by writing the following configuration in modules' config files

Module A>etc>config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
        <menu>
        <a module="A">
                <title>A</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="A">
                        <title>Manage A</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                          <action>a/adminhtml_a</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </a>
        </menu>
  <adminhtml>
```

Module B>etc>config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
        <menu>
        <b module="B">
                <title>B</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="B">
                        <title>Manage B</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                          <action>b/adminhtml_b</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </b>
        </menu>
  <adminhtml>
```

However only the link for Module B shows up under CMS menu. How can I show both links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following worked
Module A>etc>config.xml

```
 <menu>
                <cms>
                    <children>
                    <a module="A">
                        <title>A</title>
                        <sort_order>5</sort_order>               
                        <children>
                            <items module="A">
                                <title>Manage A</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>A/adminhtml_a</action>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </a>
                    </children>
                    </cms>


            </menu>
```

Module B>etc>config.xml

```
<menu>
                <cms>
                    <children>
                    <b module="B">
                        <title>B</title>
                        <sort_order>6</sort_order>               
                        <children>
                            <items module="B">
                                <title>Manage B</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                <action>B/adminhtml_b</action>
                            </items>
                        </children>
                    </b>
                    </children>
                    </cms>


            </menu>
```

Comment: Hi, I am using Magento 1.9.2.2, in the admin panel, menu item 'mobile' is not showing up, can you help me?